# Share in facebook with out refreshing the page

Tags: facebook, web, sdk, share

I want to use facebook javascript sdk to share a page on facebook, and when a user share successfully I want to be able to track that on the current page without refreshing current page.

Now I have this code bellow, that opens the dialog successfully and share as well, but the popup doesn't close when I share or cancel. it only close when I use the cross in the top right corner.

Second problem is, I don't get notified when the user share successfully.

Note : if I use the code that fires the share dialog in **$document.ready()** instead of the click event on the open link, then it closes correctly, and call the attached functions as well where I **console.log(response);** but it has the same results for both successful share or cancel.

If I use feed dialog instead, the problem with closing the dialog stays, however the notifications is fine, I get notified back with the post_id, and that is perfect but I want to use share dialog not feed.

Bellow is all the code, sorry I couldn't make a jsfiddle, I tried but couldn't get facebook app work there.

```
<a href="" class="share">Open</a>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
        $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
            FB.init({
                appId: '905779996145989',
                version: 'v2.3'
            });

        });


        $('.share').click(function() {

            /*FB.ui({
                method: 'feed',
                link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
                caption: 'An example caption'
            }, function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });*/

            FB.ui({
                method: 'share',
                href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
            }, function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: side question: why do you want to know if the user shared something? because incentivizing it would not be allowed and you can´t reward the user in any way for it.

Comment: Its basically a game where user is asked question, and when he answer wrong question he lose a life. when he loose all his three lives, he is given option to share it, and if he does the first time, he is given another life to continue from where he left.

Comment: But if I have the user sign in to my app, then I think I can do that, in which case I will use feed dialog ?

Comment: ok, that is definitely not allowed. you can´t reward the user for sharing, liking or commenting in any way. i believe they removed the possibility to check if something was shared because people usually tried to do those kind of things.

Comment: thanks @luschn , but I think if I let them sign in to my app, would it still be not allowed, this is what I get from this url : https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/08/07/Graph-API-v2.1/

" It remains acceptable to incentivize people to login to your app, checkin at a place or enter a promotion on your app’s Page"

Comment: it does not matter if you let them sign in. incentivizing and rewarding a user for sharing/liking/commenting is not allowed. period. you can only reward users for authorizing your app, but NEVER for sharing something. and THAT is the point of your question in here, right?

Comment: @luschn my point is, if they have to authorize my app before sharing, would it still not be allowed ? I am confuse with this part of the privacy policy "It remains acceptable to incentivize people to login to your app, checkin at a place or enter a promotion on your app’s Page"

Comment: i am not sure what´s so hard to understand. it does not matter if a user authorized your app, rewarding him for sharing something is NEVER allowed. with or without authorization. those are 2 different things anyway.

Comment: Ok @luschn thank you for your help. Will surely change it now.

Comment: Facebook policy states: "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions." So clearly what you are doing here is against policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse